# Groupby and extract groups containing only value with a pattern

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe such as :

```
COL1 COL2 
G1 AHA_(+)jjd
G1 6EGEGUG
G1 897E97eh
G1 77E97E
G2 8JHEJE_(-)
G2 8JHEJE_(+)
G3 TTTD
G3 YYYDD
G4 DTTDHD
G4 DYD
G5 tTDHD(+)
G6 DGDGGD
```

and I would like to add the Gnumber into a list for those that contain only COL2 value containing the pattern `()`.

her I should get

expected output :

```
print(list)

[G2,G5]
```

thanks for your help

Comment: add the expected ouput

Comment: it is the list that should contain G2 and G5

Comment: but way without `G1`?

Comment: G1 do contain also value without `()`, I only want Groups that contain `only`this pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with negate masks by `~` and test matched values by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
#filter values with ()
m1 = df['COL2'].str.contains(('\(.*\)'))
#filter COL1 values with no ()
m2 = df.COL1.isin(df.loc[~m1, 'COL1'])

#filter values only with ()
out = df.loc[~m2, 'COL1'].unique()
print (out)
['G2' 'G5']
```

Or use [`GroupBy.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.all.html) for test if all `True`s per groups and then filter index values:

```
s = df['COL2'].str.contains(('\(.*\)')).groupby(df['COL1']).all()

out = s.index[s]
print (out)
Index(['G2','G5'], dtype='object', name='COL1')
```

Comment: `G2` is missed?

Comment: @BearBrown - data was changed, so answer also `G2`